# How can I change the delimiters in .vue file?

Tags: django, vue.js, web, django-views

I'm trying to implement the signup function with django and vue.
Below is the Signup.vue

It only displays like {% csrf_token %} [[ form.as_p ]].
How can I show the form?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    [[ form.as_p ]]
    <div class="mt-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SignUp</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data() {
    return {
      form: {},
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The form is defined by using the CreateForm and the UserCreationForm as below.

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
  form_class = SignUpForm
  template_name = "Signup.vue"
  success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

  def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        login(self.request, user)
        return response
```

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
```

I had used delimiters like {{ }}, so I changed it into [[ ]].
But it didn't fix.

Comment: Shouldn't `{{ form.as_p }}`, be rendered with Django, so `{{ form.as_p }}`, not `[[ form.as_p ]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I changed to {{}}, but a white page displayed.

Comment: Aha, but likely it renders the template, but the vue component of course does not render.